# Get response body 401 spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I'm consuming a service using Spring's Rest Template. I'm getting error 401 in response: [no body]. But I'm doing the same query by postman, and I get the body. can anybody help me?

**code:**

```html
private static List<AcervoMarcSecao> assinar(List<AcervoMarcSecao> acervosMarcSecao, byte[] imgAssinatura) throws ClientException, IOException  {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        
        HttpEntity<?> request = getHttpEntity(acervosMarcSecao, imgAssinatura);
        
        try {
            response = restTemplate
                .exchange(parametros.get("SERVICE_HUB2_BASE_URL") + "/fw/v1/pdf/kms/lote/assinaturas",
                        HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
        
            if(response.getBody() != null) {
                LoteAssinaturaDTO loteAssinatura = new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(), LoteAssinaturaDTO.class);
                for(int i = 0; i < acervosMarcSecao.size(); i++) {
                    byte[] documentoAssinado = ImageRecover.recoverImageFromUrl(loteAssinatura.getDocumentos().get(i)
                            .getLinks().get(0).getHref());
                    if(documentoAssinado != null)
                        if(acervosMarcSecao.get(i).getVinculo() == null)
                            acervosMarcSecao.get(i).setVinculo(new Vinculos());
                        acervosMarcSecao.get(i).getVinculo().setArquivoAssinado(documentoAssinado);
                        acervosMarcSecao.get(i).getVinculo().setDataGravacao(new Date());
                }
            }
            
            return acervosMarcSecao;
        
        } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
            ErrorDTO error = new Gson().fromJson(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), ErrorDTO.class);
            if(error.getChave().equals("excecao.hub.perfil")) {
                throw new AlertaException(resourceBundle.getString("lblTipoAssinaturaDigitalInvalida"));
            }
            throw new AlertaException(error.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AlertaException(resourceBundle.getString("txtErroCertificarArquivo"));
        }
    }
```

[image: implementation]
[image]

**postman:**
[image]

Comment: Add code always as text not as image

Comment: 401 is "Unauthorized". Looks like you forgot to send the credentials